# Customize Odoo header background color

Tags: odoo-8

How to customize the header background color of Odoo 8.0? I spent sometime with no success. Appreciate your support.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to create a configuration module and use that module to load your CSS.

Creating an Odoo module is outside the scope of a StackOverflow answer, but see https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html

Once you have created your configuration module, you can use that to load your CSS.

First, create a CSS file `/my_module/static/src/css/website.assets_backend.css` and add your back-end CSS to that file.

Then create an XML configuration file `/my_modules/views/WebAssetsBackend.xml` to load your CSS file. The XML should like something like the following, noting that the path to the CSS file is relative to the Odoo module include path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<openerp>
  <data noupdate="1">
    <template id="assets_backend" name="My Module CSS Assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
      <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/my_module/static/src/css/website.assets_backend.css"/>
      </xpath>
    </template>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

Finally, edit the data section of `/my_module/__openerp__.py` to load your XML configuration file, noting that the path to the XML file is relative to your configuration module's root directory:

```
'data' : ['views/WebAssetsBackend.xml'],
```

Once the module has been reloaded in Odoo, you should see your CSS when viewing the back-end of the website.

You can use the same technique to update front-end CSS, simply target inherit_id="website.assets_frontend" instead of "web.assets_backend" and substitute "backend" for "frontend".

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found a solution:
I edited the file:
addons/web/static/src/css/base.css
and added the following lines at the end:

```
#oe_main_menu_navbar {
    background-color: #9a3334 !important; }

a.oe_menu_toggler {
    background-color: transparent !important; }
```

You must then Update the "web" module from Settings to see the changes.

This is not the perfect way of doing it. I will try to find a way to override the style without changing the "web" module